# Why won't this regex work with file reading and PHP? It works for other files though

Tags: php, regex

I have this code I have written to make my life easier when downloading .torrents, the code is as follows,

```
$file = 'http://kat.ph/new/';
if($file = file_get_contents($file)) {
    // RETURN ALL MAGNET URIS FROM FILE
    preg_match_all('/\"magnet\:\?xt\=urn\:btih\:(.*?)\"/x', $file, $magnetURI);
    // FOR EACH MAGNET URI RETURNED
    foreach($magnetURI[1] as $info) {
        echo '<a href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:' . $info . '">' . $info . '</a><br /><br /><br /><br />';
    }
} else {
    echo '<strong>FAIL</strong>';
}
```

It is supposed to match magnet uri links and return them to me in easy to click links, it works on other websites try replacing the file with `http://thepiratebay.se/recent/0`, but for some reason the website in the example it will not work on?!?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [works for me](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C%22magnet%5C%3A%5C%3Fxt%5C%3Durn%5C%3Abtih%5C%3A%28.%2a%3F%29%5C%22&input=%3Ca%20title%3D%22Torrent%20magnet%20link%22%20href%3D%22magnet%3A%3Fxt%3Durn%3Abtih%3ACC75C3297A9818E6469C3B4C68AAF494D4EF8C3D%26dn%3Dthe%2Bdictator%2B2012%2Bhd%2B780p%26tr%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Ftracker.publicbt.com%252Fannounce%22%20onclick%3D%22_gaq.push%28%5B%27_trackEvent%27%2C%20%27Download%27%2C%20%27Magnet%20Link%27%2C%20%27Other%27%5D%29%3B%22%20class%3D%22imagnet%20icon16%22%3E%3Cspan%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fa%3E), try removing the `x` modifier.

---

The problem is the `file_get_contents()` call, apparently kat.ph doesn't like anonymous user agents, if you try to output the `$file` variable you get a bunch of garbage like:

```
��}�r�Ʋ�o�)&\ˑ\@�Aڒ�I���X���8Y;�r �!    �Ĭ���� ϓ����.   ��ey�ĥg�랾��;�u޻��:��Q6����9�Q�[e��E�~vv��J��Z�٬��=5��n-̒>Ũc�Q�O���ip�[s�(cQ&�&�F<�m������T^oD��e��l 7j���e��]K�K�ţ�ݚ�R/ &YG���x��|��gQS�D��dq�����~�ӌ�32�2HS8�,�B��)z��x'4M�S;uq�ӝ0�NH���Z��OG�e5����Q���zhd4<ŋ�u����Ug��o+�� �H�b�8ɼiFY��f0�C���oR��e*t2��x���Մ.߭L�����,�H��7]��Q�q=1fW�   ��"?�!�{O/5��f��IH����[�DO�8Y#i�]i�S�5�R>�,=��SG��_�G��4o�,4�X�XcS� 36����wl�Vr�0D�_I�Ì%�X�*s�Q��$M�s4r| �֎�}$�g`+���0�c#7�'4S&�:|�~� ��$��S�d���y�����8 ��u{���M=P㩑����[oN����?��h`�/ћ}����R|�A � z;�0(�(���Q����=�8���>І[�ㆻF,��]��M����6!��=a4GW�+o���z��o۩s�s    ]�0��H�b�����#�/d��Z�/ԕߌ6�P�|�gE�V���dz�ćz���|�zl�ɗ�)��i���e�$�/"��l�ʟ�) ���K�ʗx��Ʉ��:9'H�$�2�ؓP�,�r/��+Fcmq]�P|���n
```

Try setting the user agent to a known browser (via `file_get_contents()` HTTP context or CURL).

Comment: It just come up with a blank page for me!! I am on wamp? would that matter?